# How to use hashAlgo=SHA256 in RSA PKCS1_OAEP encryption in pycryptodome?

Tags: python, rsa, public-key-encryption, pycryptodome

I want to use the following code to encrypt the data, but I don't know why it gives me an error in the `hashAlgo=SHA256` section:
`Expected type 'HashLikeClass | HashLikeModule | None', got 'Type[SHA256]' instead`

```
from Cryptodome.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
from Cryptodome.PublicKey import RSA
import base64

from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.hashes import SHA256

def aes_key_encryptions(data):

   key = RSA.import_key(open('rsa.public').read())
   cipher= PKCS1_OAEP.new(key, hashAlgo=SHA256)  
   signature =cipher.encrypt(data)
   base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(signature)
   base64_signature = base64_bytes.decode('ascii')
   # print()
   return base64_signature
```

The Python cryptography documentation says that you can specify  `hashAlgo=SHA256`

My public key is:

```
KEY = -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----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-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: Replace `from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.hashes import SHA256` with `from Cryptodome.Hash import SHA256`. The former is an implementation from the *Cryptography* library (which is actually not needed here), the latter from the *PyCryptodome* library, which you use for encryption. BTW, the name `signature` for the ciphertext is confusing. If you want to create a signature, see [here](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/signature/pkcs1_pss.html#pkcs-1-pss-rsa).

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing 2 different cryptography-related packages.

- `PKCS1_OAEP.new` is from the [pycryptodome](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package
- `hazmat.primitives.hashes.SHA256` is from the [pyca/cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) package

They are *not* interchangeable, as far as I know.

It's best to check the package's documentation for that method, and use the correct data types and functions provided by the package itself.

Since you are using pycrytodome's [`PKCS1_OAEP.new`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/oaep.html?highlight=hashAlgo#Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_OAEP.new):

> **hashAlgo** (*hash object*) – The hash function to use. This can be a module under `Crypto.Hash` or an existing hash object created from any of such modules. If not specified, `Crypto.Hash.SHA1` is used.

And apparently, pycryptodome has the corresponding [`Crypto.Hash.SHA256`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/hash/sha256.html):

```
from Cryptodome.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
from Cryptodome.PublicKey import RSA
from Cryptodome.Hash import SHA256  # <----

def aes_key_encryptions(data):
    key = RSA.import_key(open("rsa.public").read())
    cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(key, hashAlgo=SHA256)  # <----
    ...
```